# Javascript: Eventlistener 'keydown' not registering all keys pressed when holding down other keys

Tags: javascript, html5, keyboard

Sollution provided in the comments. The issue is that my keyboard has what is called ghosting issues, this means it doesn't support some key combinations when pressed together.

When the user holds 's' and 'd' key at the same time (movement keys, so character would move south-east), and during this presses the 'n' or 'm' key, the keydown event of the 'n' and 'm' key is not triggered. This happens with other key combinations as well, but not with all. Per example: holding down the 'w' and 'a' key will trigger the 'n' and 'm' keydown events. Is there a way to allow any keydown event to be triggered, regardless of other keys pressed? You can test this behavior using the following code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    console.log(e.key);
});
```

Comment: it might depends on your keyboard, some types of keyboard are actually incapable of seeing some combinations of keys. It's called "keyboard ghosting" . Could you double check this, as it maybe applies to your keyboard ? https://geekdroids.com/keyboard-ghosting-explained/

Comment: (and in this case, there is nothing you can do but use better hardware or rethink the usage of the keys, by looking at what is used in other games for instance, they often take into accounts this)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid ghosting when pressing multiple keys?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108996/how-to-avoid-ghosting-when-pressing-multiple-keys)

Comment: That can be the only issue, thank you for this swift response! My keyboard seems to have known ghosting issues. Luckily the n and m keys are just a temporary choice (they currently zoom the camera in and out) so this isn't a real problem. The great thing is i learned something, never knew this was a thing. Thanks again!